# Is it a common/good practice to save/update the session *after* sending the response?

Tags: http, session

I started updating the session after sending the response and it seems like a good way to get a little more speed, since it's now a non-blocking task.

But I'm worried that a minimal slow down in the database could cause problems when updating the session this way.

Imagine I want to set a session flash message for the next request, but the next request/response happen before the session is updated. The user won't see it, or he will see it in a different request.

And the worst case is when you need to regenerate the session ID. If the update is slow and the next request comes faster than that, the user will get logged out because he will be asking for a non-existent or expired session (he received the new session ID in the cookie as part of the response).

So what I wanna know is whether this has already been studied, whether people are using it, when should I do it, when I shouldn't, if there is a fix for it, etc.

Comment: This is known as premature optimization. Among other things, since you didn't measure a performance problem before "optimizing", you have no way to know if you've made things worse.

Comment: @JohnSaunders That's wrong, and I'm getting tired of that meme to be honest. For starters, I never said it was an imaginary app, and that I'm a noob. But even if it was, what's wrong with that? I'm a programmer, not a business man, nor a code monkey. Parallelizing as many tasks as possible is quite a thing in programming, in fact there are entire languages dedicated to that very problem. And even if you are a code monkey: Do you really build the shittiest app possible, and only then start think about the design and good practices? I'm not gonna do that, sorry. I'm a professional.

Comment: The professional thing to do is to build the app that meets the highest priority requirements - and then to build the app that meets the next highest priority requirements, etc. It is unprofessional to decide on your own that your "optimizations" are more important than what your stakeholders require. It may be fun to squeeze out the highest performance possible, and may be good for the ego, but may not be good for your stakeholders.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Like I said, I'm thinking and trying to solve a programming problem, not trying to deliver a product so that my boss gives me a pat in the back, and the CEO/owners get richer. Programming / software engineering is a pretty new discipline, and there's a lot of room for improvement. So now you can stop quoting "optimizations", as if I used that word, or as if I wasn't really making any improvements. Stakeholders? What? You belong to project management, so go manage a project or something. I'll be here solving programming problems, or learning about the ones already solved.

Comment: "Good practices" implies engineering, not art. Engineering is about solving problems. These are usually real problems, not imagined ones. Have fun.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Cool story bro, go make some more of those "real" apps, gotta get that paycheck! What do we want mental exercises and research for. That ain't gonna feed you! Imirite?

Comment: If you have a requirement for mental exercises and research, then please fulfill that requirement. Even research requires a metric to define "progress". Otherwise, one is likely to progress in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can't regenerate a session_id if you already sent some output. As you said he needs to receive the new_id in the cookie which is part of the http header which must be sent first. Regenerating session_id can cause issue like you mentioned if the user has multiple requests with the same session id coming and you change the session_id. For example an html page and some images which is quite commmon. If you need to regenerate session_id you should do it "separately" in a page that doesn't have other resources that needs the session so that it is an atomic operation.

Now I'm not sure which language you're using but php for example gather session information in memory and persist them at the end of process. Thus making this non-blocking...

It is true that if the session information must be synced via multiple processes you have to be careful. However this is uncommon for most web pages/applications. You rarely have multiple requests in that short amount of time (outside of the page + resources download).

Basically it's generally a good idea to update session information after the response is sent. Think of it this way: If the database is slow, it will probably have a hard time giving outdated session information. So anyway you write will probably be done by then no? ;)

Comment: First I create a new session ID. Then I add it to the cookie, and attach that to the response. Then I send the response and, while it's traveling through the wires, I save that session ID into the database. My problem is that new request might come with the old cookie, because they were sent before the response with the new cookie arrived. The language doesn't really matter, I'm more interested in the problem, whether a solution exists, and how it works. You seem to understand this, I just wanted to clarify. What I'm worried about are ajax requests, sometimes they get out of control.

Comment: I can isolate the part where I regenerate the ID (eg: during login), but what if the user has other tabs open, which periodically make ajax requests?

Comment: If it's during login, the user won't probably have other tab doing ajax call on your site (he's not logged!). But yeah, if you regenerate session_id every 1000 calls for example, there is chance that you will land in the middle of page load (with all the attached resources) and that can easily cause the issue you're talking about.

My advice, try to regenerate_id only on "page" if that's possible. Also make you ajax call handle 302 so that it retries with an increasing timeout (I'm supposing that a non-logged request get redirected (302) to a login page)

Comment: Lots of ajax requests don't require that you are logged in, eg: The price of a stock. They might even be in the homepage. I'm thinking maybe I could set a specific path in the session cookie, eg: /users. This way the cookie won't be sent when making a request to the home. But this will make for very rigid routes.

Comment: Just something I recently came across around this topic, just watch out for session locking in php. Effectively php will only let 1 concurrent request access the session data. So for ajax request even if the browser sends multiples requests in parallel, php will in fact process them linearly...

I just google php session locking and there is a few good explanation as to why and some possible solution, but those highly depends of your needs / application : e.g.: http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/